# How to prove this form of $\ln(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

It is well known that  $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}=\ln x$$

but, how can I prove this? You can't use l'hopital because the $\mathrm d/\mathrm dx$ of $x^h$ depends on this limit.

Comment: Samuel, you could let $y=x^h-1$, so $h=\dfrac{\ln(y+1)}{\ln x}$, then use the limit $\lim\limits_{y\to0}\dfrac{\ln(y+1)}y=1\;.$

Comment: @Angelo That doesn't really make sense, h will never and should never depend on x or y

Comment: If you know $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1$ you just write $x^h = e^{h\ln x}$ and expand your fraction by $\ln x$.

Comment: What is the definition of $\ln(x)$ you are using?

Comment: @AdamRubinson  Any def of ln(x) works

Comment: Ok then. I'll define $ \ln(x):= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}.\ $ Question answered.

Comment: @SamuelMorrison, it make sense, look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prove that $\;\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{x^h-1}h=\ln x\;$ without using the notable limit $\;\lim\limits_{t\to0}\dfrac{e^t-1}t=1\,,\,$ which is very similar to what you want to get, you could proceed in the following way.

Let $\;t=\dfrac1{x^h-1}\;.$

It results that $\;t\to\pm\infty\;$ as $\;h\to0^{\pm}\;,\;$ moreover ,

$h=\dfrac{\ln\left(1+\frac1t\right)}{\ln x}\;,\;$ hence ,

$\lim\limits_{h\to0^{\pm}}\dfrac{x^h-1}h=\lim\limits_{t\to\pm\infty}\dfrac{\frac1t}{\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1t\right)}{\ln x}}=\lim\limits_{t\to\pm\infty}\dfrac{\ln x}{\ln\left(1+\frac1t\right)^t}=\ln x\;,$

indeed $\;\lim\limits_{t\to\pm\infty}\left(1+\dfrac1t\right)^t=e\;.$

Answer (score 4):

Since

$\displaystyle \lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\text{e}^t-1}{t}=1$

It follows

$\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{x^h-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\text{e}^{h\log x}-1}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\text{e}^{h\log x}-1}{h\log x}\log x=\log x$

Comment: Thank you for copying my comment into an answer. :-D

Comment: It depends on what you use as definition of e; you can prove it using $ e=\lim_{n\to +\infty }\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $

Comment: @trancelocation you answer only sporadically ;)

Comment: @SineoftheTime Well spotted. +1

Comment: @SineoftheTime, the notable limit $\;\lim\limits_{t\to0}\dfrac{e^t-1}t=1\,,\,$ that you use, is very similar to the OP’s limit. The only difference is that there is “$e$” in the place of “$x$”.